# sonarqube c# set accessor error: Use the 'value' parameter in this property set accessor declaration

Tags: c#, sonarqube

```
string _frontImgPath = string.Empty;

public string FrontImagePath
{
    get
    {
        return _frontImgPath;
    }

    set
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(OriginalImgPath) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(HostUrl))
            _frontImgPath = HostUrl + OriginalImgPath;
    }
}
```

We have C# properties "OriginalImgPath" and "HostUrl" in the same class. I am getting following warning in sonarqube **"Use the 'value' parameter in this property set accessor declaration".**

Why should we use 'value' here?

Comment: What exactly is that setter supposed to be doing?  The `value` parameter is the value passed to the setter, but you're ignoring that value.  The message is telling you that it should be used because when consuming code writes `.FrontImagePath = "something"` they expect `"something"` to be used.

Comment: because when you thing.FrontImagePath="c:\x" you arent using it.. therefore its not setting the new value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling `set` in property, you are actually calling `set_FrontImagePath(string value)` method, which have parameter - `string value`. In your case you are trying to call that method without any parameters, which is giving you `Use the 'value' parameter in this property set accessor declaration"` error.

You can do something like this in your using part:

```
string _frontImgPath = string.Empty;

public string FrontImagePath
{
    get{
        return _frontImgPath;
    }
    set{
        _frontImgPath = value;
    }
}

void SomeMethod()
{
    . . .
    OriginalImgPath = "x:\\someimage.img";
    . . .
    HostUrl = "yourHostUrl";
    . . .
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(OriginalImgPath) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(HostUrl))
        FrontImagePath =  HostUrl + OriginalImgPath;
    . . .
}
```

Comment: but what should we do for such properties which need to be assigned directly but are combination value of two other properties of the same class?

Comment: can you provide some examples?

Comment: @maverick I've updated my answer with some details, you can assign your `OriginalImgPath` and `HostUrl` properties as usual, then when you want to assign `FrontImagePath`, just check your conditions in that part.

Answer (score 1):

Because if someone will call:
`FrontImagePath = "lalala"`
Value passed to the `set` method won't be used at all.

If that's the case, i think it will be better to write independent method with proper name.

Answer (score 0):

The set accessor resembles a method whose return type is `void`. It uses an implicit parameter called `value`, whose type is the type of the property. In the following example, a `set` accessor is added to the `Name` property:

```
class Person
{
    private string name;  // the name field

    public string Name    // the Name property
    {
        get { return name; }

        set { name = value; }
    }
}
```

When you assign a value to the property, the set accessor is invoked by using an argument that provides the new value. For example:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.Name = "Joe";  // the set accessor is invoked here                

System.Console.Write(person.Name);  // the get accessor is invoked here
```

It is an error to use the implicit parameter name, value, for a local variable declaration in a set accessor.

Or 
The get accessor can be used to return the field value or to compute it and return it. For example:

```
class Employee
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name != null ? name : "NA";
        }
    }
}
```